# how to convert list of string to list of int list python

Tags: python, list

I have the data like this

```
["0:0:0.123", "1:0:0.345", "2:0:0.675"]
```

Then I want to convert it to the formal like this

```
[[0,0,0.123], [1,0,0.345], [2,0,0.675]]
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. The more efficient, the better, cause the data scale is huge.

Comment: `my_string.split(':')`

Comment: `pd.Series(["0:0:0.123", "1:0:0.345", "2:0:0.675"]).str.split(':', expand=True).astype(float).values.tolist()` since you tagged pandas.

Comment: `[x.split(':') for x in data]`

Comment: `ls = [list(map(float, e.split(":"))) for e in ["0:0:0.123", "1:0:0.345", "2:0:0.675"]]`

Comment: looks like there is a few ways to do this.

Comment: `list(map(lambda x : x.split(':'),l))` just python

Comment: `[[float(s) for s in e.split(':')] for e in data]`. Although this will print the zeros as `0.0` but you need the values to be float to correctly convert the non integer values.

Comment: Since you haven't gotten any answers: `[list(map(float, re.findall(r'[.\d]+', i))) for i in x]`

Comment: @PaulRooney, unless of course we know that the only floats are in the third field, then the first two need to be ints...

Comment: In your title it says that you want to convert a list of strings to a list of int list. That would seem to mean a list of lists of ints.  But in your example, the output has lists of lists of two ints and a float.  So, perhaps you want numeric types according to the string elements in the input?

Comment: @Lilian417 how huge is huge? 10\*\*6? 10\*\*9? larger than RAM? larger than SSD? larger than one machine?

Comment: @DimaTisnek the whole file is 5G

Comment: Consider using `numpy.genfromtxt()` if your data fits the criteria, typically if each datum is same type and length or can be represented as such, like 3-tuple of floats in the example.
For heterogeneous data with fixed number of columns, `pandas` is great.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ["0:0:0.123", "1:0:0.345", "2:0:0.675"]
b = [ [float(d) for d in c.split(':')] for c in a ]

print( b )
```

Produces

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.123], [1.0, 0.0, 0.345], [2.0, 0.0, 0.675]]
```

If you specifically want integers where the strings are integer, you can do it like this,

```
a = ["0:0:0.123", "1:0:0.345", "2:0:0.675"]
b = [ [ ( float(d) if '.' in d else int(d) ) for d in c.split(':')] for c in a ]
print(b)
```

which produces

```
[[0, 0, 0.123], [1, 0, 0.345], [2, 0, 0.675]]
```

Or, if you want to use try - except, you can define a function to parse the strings,

```
def myparse(a):
    try:
        return int(a)
    except:
        return float(a)
```

and then

```
a = ["0:0:0.123", "1:0:0.345", "2:0:0.675"]
b = [ [myparse(d) for d in c.split(':')] for c in a ]
print(b)
```

again produces

```
[[0, 0, 0.123], [1, 0, 0.345], [2, 0, 0.675]]
```

QED